# Edge and canvas.toDataUrl() giving incorrect/truncated value;

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, canvas, microsoft-edge, todataurl

I am trying to render a thumbnail image from a video element. The code below works in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Edge, and of course not in IE.

You'll see I'm `console.log`ing the length of the resulting value. In Chrome it's a healthy 318210, but in Edge it comes back 3338. Sometimes (only sometimes) subsequent screen refresh gives the right value and the image is displayed, so maybe it's a race condition? But I'm not sure what I'm racing, or how to win.

Here is the code (TypeScript):

```
public getVideoThumbnailUrl(url: string): Promise<string> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.videoElement = document.createElement('video');
            this.videoElement.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');
            this.videoElement.onerror = e => reject(e);
            this.videoElement.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => this.videoMetadataLoaded(resolve));
            this.videoElement.src = url;
            this.taskQueue.queueMicroTask(
                (() => {
                    this.videoElement.muted = true;
                    this.videoElement.load();
                    this.videoElement.play();
                }).bind(this)
            );
        });
    }

    private videoMetadataLoaded(resolve: (url: string) => void) {
        this.videoElement.addEventListener('timeupdate', () => this.videoOnTimeUpdate(resolve));
        this.videoElement.currentTime = 0;
    }

    private videoOnTimeUpdate(resolve: (url: string) => void): void {
        this.videoElement.removeEventListener('timeupdate', () => this.videoOnTimeUpdate(resolve));
        console.log(this.videoElement);
        const canvasElement = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvasElement.width = this.videoElement.videoWidth;
        canvasElement.height = this.videoElement.videoHeight;
        canvasElement
            .getContext('2d')
            .drawImage(this.videoElement, 0, 0, this.videoElement.videoWidth, this.videoElement.videoHeight);
        const videoThumbnailSrc: string = canvasElement.toDataURL();
        console.log(videoThumbnailSrc.length);
        resolve(videoThumbnailSrc);
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated, and also help with the famous IE `SecurityError` issue. It seems setting `crossorigin` on the `<video>` element has no effect in IE.

Comment: Unrelated but note that your removeEventListener won't work here, you must pass a reference to the same function you used for addEventListener, not just one that looks the same. For your issue, you may want to try an other frame than the one at `currentTime: 0`.

Comment: Is there any error message? Try to use F12 developer tools to check whether there have error message and whether the request is success? If you can post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it will be easier us to help you solve the problem. Besides, as far as I know, we could specify an image to be shown while the video is downloading by using [the <video> poster Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_poster.asp).

Comment: @Kaiido, changing the current time didn't work, but thanks for pointing out about the event listener issue!

@ZhiLv-MSFT, there are no errors. Just the `length` log I put in there. When I inspect the `<img>` element, it does have a data URL in the src ... just not a complete one. So Edge doesn't know it's failing.

This is running in a framework (Aurelia) so it's not possible to post a full example. I think Aurelia is rendering the element before the data URL is complete, but I'm not sure where to get in there and make it wait. Maybe I can explore different events than `loadedmetadata`.

Comment: You could try to use the [loadeddata event](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_loadeddata.asp). Besides, here is some samples about manipulating video using canvas, you could refer to them: [Link 1](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_drawimage_video) and [Link 2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Manipulating_video_using_canvas)

Comment: Thanks! This is very useful :)